# Получить строку-разметку элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли как-то в `javaScript/jQuery`, имея сам элемент, получить строку с его html-разметкой?

Comment: `element.outerHTML`

Comment: jquery:  $('selector').html();

Answer (score -1):

Элемент `<template>` предназначен для хранения «образца» разметки, невидимого и предназначенного для вставки куда-либо.

Конечно, есть много способов записать произвольный невидимый текст в HTML. В чём же особенность `<template>`?

Его отличие от обычных тегов в том, что его содержимое обрабатывается особым образом. Оно не только скрыто, но и считается находящимся вообще «вне документа». А при вставке автоматически «оживает», выполняются из него скрипты, начинает проигрываться видео и т.п.

Содержимое тега `<template>`, в отличие, к примеру, от шаблонов или `<script type="неизвестный тип">`, обрабатывается браузером. А значит, должно быть корректным HTML.

Оно доступно как `DocumentFragment` в свойстве тега *content*. Предполагается, что мы, при необходимости, возьмём content и вставим, куда надо.

Вставка шаблона

Пример вставки шаблона tmpl в Shadow DOM элемента elem:

```
<p id="elem">
   Доброе утро, страна!
</p>

<template id="tmpl">
  <h3><content></content></h3>
  <p>Привет из подполья!</p>
  <script>
    document.write('...document.write:Новость!');
  </script>
</template>

<script>
  var root = elem.createShadowRoot();
  root.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
</script>
```

У нас получилось, что:

1. В элементе #elem содержатся данные в некоторой оговорённой разметке.
2. Шаблон #tmpl указывает, как их отобразить, куда и в какие HTML-теги 
   завернуть содержимое #elem.
3. Здесь шаблон показывается в Shadow DOM тега. Технически, это не 
   обязательно, шаблон можно использовать и без Shadow DOM, но тогда не 
   сработает тег `<content>`.

Можно также заметить, что скрипт из шаблона выполнился. Это важнейшее 
отличие вставки шаблона от вставки HTML через `innerHTML` и от обычного 
`DocumentFragment`.

Также мы вставили не сам `tmpl.content`, а его клон. Это обычная практика, 
чтобы можно было использовать один шаблон много раз.

Comment: а как данный ответ относится к заданному вопросу про **получение** разметки элемента?

Comment: Хороший ответ. Возможно, на него еще зададут вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо бы еще указывать [источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/template-tag), откуда все слово в слово скопировано.

Comment: Стоит под этот ответ самостоятельно задать вопрос и отпубликовать там ответом, а тут удалить. т. к. к вопросу вообще не относится. Ну и да, имеет смысл указать источник в PS, если действительно всё оттуда.